# How to write base64 string to file as file data - nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, node.js-fs

How to write a base64 string as the file data.

I have an entire video sent to me as a base64 string, I would like to write the data to a file using NodeJS

Here is my existing code.
`mergedData` is a very very large string

```js
let outputFileName = "myfile.mp4";
let mergedData = "BASE64 DATA GOES HERE";
let decodeData = Buffer.from(mergedData, "base64");
fs.writeFileSync(outputFileName, decodeData);
```

The `myfile.mp4` file size is `20 bytes` where it should be roughly `1MBs`

Comment: Do you have _just_ the binary video data encoded as base64 there - or a Data URI?

Comment: How long is the base64 string? (`console.log(mergedData.length)`)

Comment: @Pointy here is the base64 string https://free.keep.sh/MIH1Y1Q10M8FG8ur/mergedData.dat

Comment: OK well how exactly is the variable `mergedData` being populated with that content? Are you reading it from a file? If so, how?

Comment: @Pointy i'm loading that from and array of frames into a large string which is `mergedData`

Comment: the length is `4500000`

Comment: OK, well you can also check the Buffer length with `decodeData.length`. It should be less than the string size, but still a large number.

Comment: I've tried the code you posted with the content you linked and it works fine, I end up with a 2.4MB file.

Comment: @Pointy could provide an answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my very slightly adjusted version of your code:

```
import fs from "node:fs";

const merged = fs.readFileSync("/Users/emfive/Downloads/mergedData.dat", "utf-8");

const decoded = Buffer.from(merged, "base64");

console.log("original: " + merged.length);

console.log("decoded: " + decoded.length);

fs.writeFileSync("foo.mp4", decoded);
```

It takes no time to run, reading the source and writing the decoded result in under a second. There's no need for streams or "chunked" operations.

If the code in the question is not working, then there's something about it that has not been shared. For example, when you read in the base64 content, you have to make sure you're reading a string (by adding "utf-8" to the `readFileSync()` method).

Answer (score 1):

the issue may be that the decoded data is not complete, leading to a smaller file size than expected.

To ensure that the entire base64 string is decoded, you can try this:

```
let outputFileName = "myfile.mp4";
let mergedData = "BASE64 DATA GOES HERE";
let chunkSize = 1024; 
let decodedData = Buffer.alloc(0);

for (let i = 0; i < mergedData.length; i += chunkSize) {
  let chunk = mergedData.substr(i, chunkSize);
  decodedData = Buffer.concat([decodedData, Buffer.from(chunk, "base64")]);
}

fs.writeFileSync(outputFileName, decodedData);
```

Comment: this doesnt seem to be working

Comment: here is the base64 - https://keep-sh.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/1/MIH1Y1Q10M8FG8ur/mergedData.dat?X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=Q7JO64AWYT56RHKZGOE3%2F20230310%2Fnyc3%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20230310T140001Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-Signature=22093fd3202c921c194ea3b584b8b842bc0b72ccda94ad309c2548e58081fb35

Comment: There's no need for this, the code posted by the OP works fine.

Answer (score 1):

use a stream instead of writing it individually

Comment: `writeFileSync()` *should* work fine; it's a large file but well within the capacity of a modern computer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.